# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLTableElement.<'anonymous'> Update

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have c # code in asp.net view: (It create time inputs for me with the class described)

**View:**

```
<td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].Rozpoczecie, new { @class = "start", @type = "time" })</td>
<td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].Zakonczenie, new { @class = "end", @type = "time" })</td>
<td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].OdbiorGodzin, new { @class = "gethours", @type = "time" })</td>


<td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].DniOdpracowania, new { @class = "additional_free",@type = "time", @readonly = true })</td>
<td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].SaldoNadgodzin, new { @class = "overtime", @type = "time", @readonly = true })</td>
```

And I have a code that does various calculations for me:

**JavaScript**

```
table.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    const classList = e.target.classList;
    if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end') || classList.contains('gethours')) {
        //retrieve the associated inputs
        const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        const [additional_free, overtime] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.additional_free,.overtime')];

        additional_free.value = overtime.value     <<<<<<<<<< this


    }
});
```

Although everything works, I get such an unknown for me error:

> VM49:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at HTMLTableElement. (:85:42)

I will add that the data at the beginning are read from the database and set as the initial values ​​in this table

Anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to fully understand the reasons but you can try the following:

```
const [additional_free, overtime] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.additional_free,.overtime')];

try {
    additional_free.value = overtime.value  
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(JSON.Stringify(additional_free));
    console.log(JSON.Stringify(overtime));
}
```

Please add the output in your question for us to help you more.

Comment: ypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:88:46)  \\ on console.log(err);   ||||||||
VM35:91 Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Stringify is not a function
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:91:30) \\ on  console.log(JSON.Stringify(additional_free));